# NoSuchBeanException for MapStruct generated classes in Micronaut

Tags: java, mapstruct, micronaut

When generating mapper-implementations with MapStruct, using "jsr330" componentModel, micronaut will throw a NoSuchBeanException during runtime when trying to inject those.

A workaround would be to use a provider that will supply the mapper-objects, but the generated code should work.

Mapper definition:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "jsr330")
public interface FooBarMapper {
    Foo toFoo(Bar bar);
}
```

Controller:

```
@Controller
public class SomeController {
    @Inject
    public SomeController(FooBarMapper mapper) {
    }

    @Get
    public String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

pom.xml excerpt:

```
<annotationProcessorPaths>
    <path>
        <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
        <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
        <version>${mapstruct.version}</version>
    </path>
    <path>
        <groupId>io.micronaut</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-inject-java</artifactId>
        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
    </path>
    <path>
        <groupId>io.micronaut.configuration</groupId>
        <artifactId>micronaut-openapi</artifactId>
        <version>${micronaut.version}</version>
    </path>
</annotationProcessorPaths>
```

When calling the method on the controller, I would expect Micronaut to find the Mapstruct generated class (it is annotated with @Singleton), but instead, the result is

Message: No bean of type [com.example.FooBarMapper] exists. Ensure the class is declared a bean and if you are using Java or Kotlin make sure you have enabled annotation processing.
Path Taken: new SomeController([FooBarMapper mapper])
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.DependencyInjectionException: Failed to inject value for parameter [mapper] of class: com.example.SomeController

Comment: Are the mappers generated?

Comment: Yes, mappers have been generated and I can also instantiate one manually in the controller. Just the wiring using @Inject doesn't work.

Comment: When is this message coming from Micronaut? During compilation or runtime? Maybe micronaut is not waiting for the other annotation processors

Comment: During runtime, if I change the order of annotation processors in the pom, so that mapstruct is after micronaut, no mapstruct code is generated.

Comment: This is a known issue see https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/issues/991

Comment: Ah ok - was suspecting something like that, still - unfortunately - does not explain my other problem, but thanks for your time so far.

Comment: Yes it doesn't explain the problem. Unfortunately I don't know much about Micronaut to help with that

Comment: The issue has been resolved in core and will be included in the next release, although the example will still not work as is as `Mapper` instances are not automatically Micronaut beans. You would have to define a `@Factory` with an `@Bean` that returns the mapper to make it a bean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [Micronaut PR](https://github.com/micronaut-projects/micronaut-core/pull/1339) which should resolve the problem with mapstruct using `jsr330` component model. They are planning to include the fix in `1.1.0`.

UPDATE: The issue if fixed in `1.1.0.RC1`

Comment: Thank you for the effort - this is exactly what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing issue even after using @SirWojtek answer. Below changes worked for me: Add generated directory as source code.

```
sourceSets {
    main.java.srcDirs += "build/generated/sources/annotationProcessor/java/main"
}
```